# Appendix table numbering

Tags: tables, appendices

I'm writing an article with an appendix which contains tables and graphs. Successive graphs are appropriately numbered "Figure A1", "Figure A2", "Figure A3", "Figure A4" and so on. But successive tables are numbered "Table A1", "Table A3", "Table A5", "Table A7" and so on. None of the solutions posted here have worked for me. I simply want the tables and graphs numbered according to A1, A2, A3, A4. I would be grateful for any clues.

Here is my tex file. Sorry it's long, but I thought I should include as much information as possible from  my preamble. I have also added an image of the tables.

EDIT: In response to Don Hosek I have now posted below the content of the input files "groupstats_wt2.tex" and "groupstats_wt3.tex".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.3pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}        
\captionsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-0.60em}#1} %% to create indents for variable headings


\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\newcommand{\beginsupplement}{% complete program to generate appendix with tables
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}%    
}



\begin{document}
    
\section{Introduction}
    
This this thh yh yh yhy hyyhhyh  yh ehy w hyh hy yhw hy whyhyyyk yhyhyh wh yhy hyhyhy
the ahtenn tt ehhtkt yh hyhe yhyr wrt eth theo y yheet yhehth hyp yhhyor yhy rorooy rr.

\section*{Appendix}
\beginsupplement

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5%%%%% Tables %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering
    \caption{Presser et al (2008) measure of work scheduling}
    \scriptsize\input{groupstats_wt2.tex}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering
    \caption{Presser et al (2008) measure of work scheduling: all employees}
    \scriptsize\input{groupstats_wt3.tex}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]\centering
    \caption{New employees}
    \scriptsize\input{groupstats_wt3.tex}
\end{table}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% GRAPHS 


\end{document}
```

The input file \input{groupstats_wt2.tex} is as follows

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{longtable}{l*{3}{cc}}
\toprule\endfirsthead\midrule\endhead\midrule\endfoot\endlastfoot
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Male} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Female}\\
            &        Mean&        S.D.&        Mean&        S.D.&        Mean&        S.D.\\
\midrule
Nonday      &        0.13&        0.34&        0.16&        0.37&        0.08&        0.28\\
Weekend     &        0.46&        0.50&        0.51&        0.50&        0.39&        0.49\\
\midrule
\(N\)       &       14812&            &        8954&            &        5858&            \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
```

The input file \input{groupstats_wt3.tex} is as follows

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{longtable}{l*{3}{cc}}
\toprule\endfirsthead\midrule\endhead\midrule\endfoot\endlastfoot
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Full} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Male} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Female}\\
            &        Mean&        S.D.&        Mean&        S.D.&        Mean&        S.D.\\
\midrule
Nonday      &        0.13&        0.34&        0.16&        0.37&        0.09&        0.28\\
Weekend     &        0.49&        0.50&        0.54&        0.50&        0.41&        0.49\\
\midrule
\(N\)       &       16658&            &       10312&            &        6346&            \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Everything looked fine in your code so I tried running your code, but not having the referenced input files, I just commented out those lines and I got tables A1–A3. This tells me that there's something in the input files that's advancing the table counter. Without seeing one of those files, there's no way of knowing what exactly is causing the difficulty.

Comment: I will now paste the content of the input files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `longtable` is by itself already a floating environment (unlike `tabular`). So nesting a `longtable` in a `table` environment will advance the table counter twice instead of once.

So, if instead of nesting them, you add the `longtable` like so:

```
\begin{longtable}{l*{3}{cc}}
    \caption{}
\end{longtable}
```

it will be correctly numbered and also have the initial "A", which it takes from your re-definition of the `table` caption.

Comment: Yikes, I can kind of understand what David was doing when he made the `\refstepcounter{table}` part of the code for `\begin{longtable}` but it's unfortunate that this behaves differently than the `table` environment which doesn't do `\refstepcounter` until an actual caption is typeset.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Markus. Problem solved.

Comment: @DonHosek I'm not sure what you're getting at. Are you saying, that my answer is not technically correct but a hack? Then maybe you can suggest something else?! I'd really hate to give people bad advice. I mean, this answer will probably stay here and be seen by more people, so if there is a "good practice" way of doing this, I'm all ears.

Comment: No, your answer is fine, I think that the decision by David Carlisle in writing `longtable` to have the environment step the `table` counter rather than having it done by the `\caption` command was not the correct choice, but that ship sailed 30 years ago.